# Can you intercept a local variable in a closure without eval?

Tags: javascript

I am writing some JavaScript profiling bits and need to be able to intercept methods inside a closure.

I managed to get this working:

```
var t = (function() {

  var echo = function(v) { console.log("calling echo with " + v); }; 

  return {
    intercept: function(n, f) {
      var old = eval(n);
      var newFunction = (function(that, old){
        return f(that, old);
      })(this, old);
      eval(n + " = newFunction ");
    },
    getEchoFunction: function() { return echo; }
  };  
})(); 


var c = t.getEchoFunction();

c("hello");



t.intercept("echo", function(that,old){
  return function() {
    console.log("before echo");
    old.apply(that,arguments);
    console.log("after echo");
  };
});


c = t.getEchoFunction();

c("world");
```

Output is:

```
"calling echo with hello"
"before echo"
"calling echo with world"
"after echo"
```

So, this "intercept" API lets me intercept and re-write function declarations hidden in a closure.

However, there is much complaining about eval in the world.

Is there any way to write the same API without needing to use `eval` in the `intercept` function?

Comment: What happens if you use `this[n] = newFunction`? But if there isn't another way to do it, this seems like a legitimate use of `eval` anyways.

Comment: `this` points to the global object, is undefined/null (strict mode) or points to an object - but never to another scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no way to access a non-global scope similar to how `window[...]` works.

However, depending on what you need to do using an object instead of a native scope would be a good idea.

Comment: It sure would have been handy in javascript for cases like this if there was a pre-defined symbol for the local scope so one could access all local variables off that object.

Comment: Indeed, but it doesn't seem to be very common unfortunately. Even in Python they did not add a way to access such a scope until lately (`nonlocal` in py3k)

Comment: I am pretty sure Perl has this as well, Ruby are resistant to adding cleaner way of exposing bindings further up the stack